# Shoulda, Rails Tests , and Autotest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, automated-tests, shoulda, autotest

I'm trying to model my tests after the great work that the Thougtbot guys have done. They seem to use the test framework built into Rails Shoulda. Great.

I have been hearing a lot about Autotest - that its magical-ness should make things easier.... I expected that things would 'just work' if I installed it. My rake test:units already all pass. When I run autotest, nothing happens. I've barely found any information on how autotest works, and only brief mentions of a special file '.autotest' that's supposed to do something other than hold the requires for growl and redgreen.

I'm coming from a CruiseControl background here... but it seems like things should be way more apparent. Does anybody have experience running Rails' native tests along with Shoulda and Autotest?

**Update|Resolved** apparently the discover.rb file in seed-fu was making autotest think it was testing for RSpec, not Test::Unit.

Comment: I don't think Shoulda is built into Rails: test/unit is there, and there's support in recent versions for minitest. Are you working on Windows or *nix? I - just about - got autotest working on Windows, but it was painful and unreliable and I soon gave up.

Comment: I'm on OSX and have shoulda installed as a gem. It enhances test::unit afaik. I'm all for using something better than Autotest if it's available !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A plugin I'm using, seed-fu, had a discover.rb to 'help' autotest. In my case though it made autotest think I was running RSpec and everything else broke.